# Bluetooth - poor sound quality for regular user (JBL Speaker)

Tags: sound, bluetooth

After connecting JBL Speaker via Bluetooth sound quality is ok for my user (admin).
Another user with no admin rights gets crappy mono radio-like sound and is unable to change sound mode option to High Fidelity, always switches back to Headset.

Answer (score 1):

I might be a bit late, but today I had the same issue. The solution was to click on sound settings, pick JBL and switch the mode to High Fidelity Playback.

Comment: There's a problem with this setting, it causes video playback to hang, stutter etc., youtube player stops and plays only when sound settings are changed to system speakers. It must be some problem with bluetooth drivers...under Ubuntu it works like a charm.